# How to display numeric value which was state stored in state to TextInput?

Tags: react-native

I was just learning react native, Now i was just trying arithmetic app.On that i have just stored two numeric values in state when I press submit button the result is want to display in TextInput.I was change TextInput editable:false so I can't edit want to show result only.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the result in TextInput . Get final added value in state and assign this final state to TextInput value.

For ex:

```
this.state = {
int1:2,
int2:3,
result:0,
} 

let val = this.state.int1 + this.state.int2;
this.setState({
  result:val,
});

<TextInput
     maxLength={160}
     multiline={false}
     underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
     editable={false}
     style={styles.input}
     value={this.state.result}
   />
```